# How to add different values for the same CSS property in the same element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

I am trying to add the same CSS property multiple times with different values each time for the same selector, with jQuery.

```
$('.element').css({
  'cursor':'-moz-grab',
  'cursor':'-webkit-grab',
  'cursor':'move'
});
```

How can I do this, without each time overwriting the same css property?

Comment: Add a CSS class, that will be cleaner and better approach.

Comment: Yea thanks, but I'm still interested to know if it's possible in the scenario that the values are always dynamically changing

Answer (score 2):

Add to your CSS a class with desired rules.

```
.addclass{
  cursor:-moz-grab;
  cursor:-webkit-grab;
  cursor:move;
}
```

and then add this class to your element

```
$('.element').addClass('addclass');
```

Comment: Yea this is the cleaner way, but I'm still interested to know if it's possible in the scenario that the values are always dynamically changing

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, as I had to add dynamic css depending on user inputs.

In your case, this is not necessary, as you have a very well defined css, it just adds cursor, so adding a class will be a better option.

In the case you need to add, like me some dynamic changing color that the user selects, you can use the following code.

You have to do this for each element, so you can extract each element style individually, otherwise $elm.attr("style") will return the first element styles or undefined, not sure, unless you only have one element with class "element"

```
$('.element').each(function(idx, elm) {

    var $elm = $(elm);
    // This will add standard CSS
    $elm.css({ 'cursor':'move'});

    // This will add fallbacks

    $elm.attr("style", $elm.attr("style") + ";cursor:-moz-grab;cursor:-webkit-grab");

});
```

Comment: Question is, do you have to use that fallback so you can have the same CSS property with different values?

Comment: Yes, as jquery .css({cursor:"move"}) actually removes any other "cursor" properties, including the fallbacks, and that's also why it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mg0wy58/)

```
$('.element').attr("style", "cursor:moz-grab; cursor:-webkit-grab; cursor:move;" );

Or

$('.element').css({"cursor":"moz-grab","cursor":"-webkit-grab" ,"cursor":"move"  })

Or

.addclass{
  cursor:-moz-grab;
  cursor:-webkit-grab;
  cursor:move;
}
```

And then add  that class using  `addClass`

Comment: Note, however, that this will remove any inline styles already present, including anything previously added using `$.css`.

Comment: same answer, few second later :)

Comment: The first option removes all styles the current element has.

The second option does ONLY inclue the last "cursor" property.

The third option does not allow any dynamic CSS unless you inline the css with javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the style attribute.

```
$('.element').attr("style", "cursor:-moz-grab;cursor:-webkit-grab;cursor:move");
```

Comment: For others to note, this will remove any inline styles already present, including anything previously added using `$.css`

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.element').each(function() {

    var eleStyle = "";
    if($(this).attr('style')) eleStyle = $(this).attr('style');

    $(this).attr(
        'style', eleStyle + 'cursor:-moz-grab; cursor:-webkit-grab; cursor:move;'
    );

});
```

Comment: I am getting undefined for `$(this).attr('style')`, I guess because there are no styles on the element as it stands. Also you have an odd curly bracket there - I cannot edit your answer as it is only a one character typo

Comment: I have edited the answer, to what seems to work i.e. keeping already present element styles intact

Comment: This is a needlessly verbose and overcomplicated way of implementing functionality that [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) gives you for free - and would be all the more verbose and overcomplicated if you hadn't omitted to deal properly with the cause where the element doesn't already have a `style` attribute.

Comment: @RickySmith your attempt to improve a suggested edit to this answer actually broke it.

Comment: @ricky-smith This code you have written does not apply the style, if no inline styles exist on the element. It needs to apply the styles in any case

Comment: Apologies. My edit was actually based on a review of another person's edit, not based on the original code. I've submitted a rollback.